# Laravel 10.4, Cannot redeclare function in api.php route file

Tags: php, laravel, function

I do not see the error. After I declare a function "common" in the api.php file I get an error message when running "php artisan optimize" which says: "Cannot redeclare common() (previously declared in /app/routes/api.php:21)".

The following function was declared:

```
function common(string $scope)
{
    Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', $scope])->group(function() {
        Route::get('user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
        Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
        Route::put('users/info', [AuthController::class, 'updateInfo']);
        Route::put('users/password', [AuthController::class, 'updatePassword']);
    });
}
```

The function was declared only 1x.

Error message is:

```
Whoops\Exception\ErrorException. 

  Cannot redeclare common() (previously declared in /app/routes/api.php:21)

  at routes/api.php:21
     17▕ | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
     18▕ | be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
     19▕ |
     20▕ */
  ➜ 21▕ function common(string $scope)
     22▕ {
     23▕ Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
     24▕ Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
     25▕ 

      +1 vendor frames 

  2 [internal]:0
      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe "common" is a function that already exists somewhere in the Laravel ecosystem (it's a common name...). Try to add `if(!function_exists("common"))` (maybe there is a typo im from my phone)

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but then I also tried "commonxyz" and resulted in the same misbehavior

Comment: Maybe because the `api.php` is loaded 2 times or more. Have you tried to add the if statement that @Jack gave you?

Comment: Can you give more information like whole api route? or log completely? Also try `php artisan optimize:clear` and comment the results

Comment: @MahdiRashidi yes i tried but then display the same error

Comment: @AnthonyRave try with condition will work but this one: if (!function_exists('common')) { function common(string $scope) {.. that means if the funktion not exists...? weird....

Comment: run `compser dump` to refresh the auto-loading

Comment: remove the function, run `php artisan route:cache` then redo it and run `php artisan route:cache` again. I believe it's caching issue

Comment: I duplicated the function and ran `php artisan optimize`. After throwing error although I removed the duplicated function it still showing the error. Maybe the ecosystem of caching compares the cached value to the original one.

Comment: as i wrote, only with condition `function_exists` the function will work. this is weird

Answer (score 0):

`if(!function_exists("common"))` will solve this problem. I had the same situation. The code will look like this:

```
if (!file_exists('common')) {
    function common(string $scope)
    {
        Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
        Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

        Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', $scope])->group(function () {
            Route::get('user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
            Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
            Route::put('users/info', [AuthController::class, 'updateInfo']);
            Route::put('users/password', [AuthController::class, 'updatePassword']);
        });
    }
}
```